# Custom Styles Applying to page.html.twig but not html--front.html.twig

Tags: theming

I'm new to drupal and am trying to make my own theme. Currently I have a `page.html.twig` for my pages, and my css styles show up fine. However, when I added a `html--front.html.twig` file, cleared the caches, and checked the homepage, there were no styles, even ones that apply to elements that are in every page (such as `body`). The code in `html--front.html.twig` is identical to the code in `page.html.twig`. I checked the console and the front page *is* successfully templating from `html--front.html.twig`. Every other page works fine. I just don't see why it is now ignoring all my styles for the front page. Here is the code for both pages:

```
<header role="banner">
    {{ page.header }}
  </header>
<div class="layout-container">
  <main role="main">
    <a id="main-content" tabindex="-1"></a>{# link is in html.html.twig #}

    <div class="layout layout-content">
      {{ page.content }}
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Why would the code in html.html.twig be identical to page.html.twig? My first thought is that you are not printing styles or attaching librarie(s) that are being attached via say a hook_page_attachment_alter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The code in html--front.html.twig is identical to the code in page.html.twig

That's your problem - those are two different templates, it doesn't make sense for them to have the same content.

html.html.twig *contains* (or more accurately, renders) page.html.twig, plus the `<head>` tags and all that lives within, the footer of the document, and so on. If you copied page.html into html.html, that explains why you don't see styles any more - your `<head>` is gone.

It's perfectly valid to have html--front.html.twig and page--front.html.twig, or some other combination, but the html template needs to contain the outer part of the document, and the page template needs to contain the inner part.

Comment: Well I could change the content in page--front.html.twig, but I mainly kept it the same because I just wanted to see if I could create a custom twig page in principle.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm still a little confused. I put the code for the page in my question. What are you saying I need to remove for the html--front.html.twig?

Comment: html—front should be rather identical to html.html.twig, NOT page.html.twig.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain it very well @CalebBertrand...templates are hierarchical; the top-level template is html.html.twig, which contains the wrapping markup for the page `<html><head><body>`. Within the `<body>` tag the variable `page` is rendered. That's the result of page.html.twig, or page--front.html.twig, or whatever other template happens to be used for that request. html--front.html.twig is used when you want to change html.html.twig, the wrapping markup for the html document, for the front page only. If I understand your markup/question properly, you just need a page--front.html.twig